# Laravel 10 Vue3 password-reset link works in development but not on production server

Tags: vuejs3, laravel-10, laravel-sanctum, laravel-breeze

I use a laravel 10 api with Breeze auth scaffolding and with VueJS 3 as frontend.

I can register and login in both production an development mode.

But when trying the forgot password functionality, things work fine until the reset link is emailed.

Nevertheless, when using the link which seems perfect https://subdomain.domain.fr/password-reset/token_here?email=email_here, it works in development mode but not in production.

In production I got a page not found error.

```
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```